# How can I render an image inside a callout component in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render a clickable image on my map. I tried this but it did not work, as the image never shows and no error is shown.

```
     <MapView.Callout>
    <View style={styles.callout}>
    <Image
          style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
          source={{uri: '../assets/whaleimage.png'}}></Image>
     </View>
  </MapView.Callout>
```

I'm temporarily using this while I find a solution.

```
     <MapView.Callout>
    <View style={styles.callout}>
      <Button title='Send Sonar' onPress={() => console.log('Clicked')} />
    </View>
  </MapView.Callout>
```

How can I render a clickable image on my MapView?

Comment: have you tried TouchOpacity?

Comment: Not sure, but seems like you forgotten to put element that process clicks like TouchableOpacity or something like onResponderRelease on View.

Comment: the problem I have is that the image never shows!